# Can you give some example passage that is not so easy to decide whether to interpret the passage literally or metaphorically?

Tags: exegesis

For example in ps.80:8-16 there is vine which is easy use analyze that it is metaphorically about Israel. 
But it still doesn't say in this passage that what vine is like, but it has to be analyzed from the context. 
But then I have heard that all prophecies in the bible unless otherwise stated are to be interpreted literally like the rebirth of nation of Israel in Isaiah.66:8? And I have heard that unless it is seen evidently from the passage that interpretation is to be taken metaphorically, one should interpret passage literally. Is this correct strategy for interpretation of a passage of the bible? So when to use literal and when allegorical/metaphorical interpretation method?
Can you give some example passage that is not so easy to decide whether to interpret the passage literally or metaphorically?

Comment: I think we do not entertain questions on how to interpret scripture.

Comment: @Mawia. Can you clarify the reasons for this stance?

Comment: Hi @laovultai, I offered an edit that gives the question a more specific scope. You can find answers to your question [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq). Thanks.

Comment: @Philip Schaff. What do you think concerning the betterment of this question if I add: When to use literal meaning for a passage in the bible and when allegorical/metaphorical one according to charismatic/pentecostal tradition/doctrine? Or is question on-topic righ now already?

Comment: @laovultai: I think your suggested edit would be a clear improvement. Ultimately it's up to the community, with high-rep users as the community's representatives, to decide which questions are / are not placed on hold or reopened following improvement. The overall idea is to phrase questions in a way that they can be answered by reference to external standards, rather than individual users' interpretations.

Comment: The body of the question is a bit rambling, but the Subject line is a great question, which is only a duplicate if you think Fundamentalist literalism is the only viewpoint that matters. An informed Answerer could provide a brief survey of the major modes of criticism, and the controversies involved.

Comment: I changed question again, because my original question( When to use literal and when allegorical/metaphorical interpretation method conserning bible passage?) was considered closed and current restated question, which was more general did not expressed my views. So my current question is simply about problematic passages that seems difficult to decide whether to use literal of metaphorical interpretation. This is at least one thing that I would like to know: What passages are difficult to interpret in terms of whether to interpret them literally or metaphorically. Even just one passageisenough